# Cairo package installation in R

Tags: r, package

I have set up a brand new environment of R using anaconda2 on a unix platform as a server user. I tried to install a few packages, including 'Cairo' but keeping getting a compiling error.
Any thought will be helpful!

Here is what I did in the R environment:

```
conda install -c r r
conda install -c r r-essential
```

in R console

```
install.packages('Cairo')

.....
.....
checking for PNG support in Cairo... yes
checking for ATS font support in Cairo... no
configure: CAIRO_LIBS=-lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpng12 -lz -lXrender -lcairo -lX11  
checking for library containing deflate... no
checking whether Cairo programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot compile a simple Cairo program. See config.log for details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'Cairo'
* removing 'path/lib/R/library/Cairo'
```

Here is the sessioninfo()

```
> sessionInfo() 
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /path/anaconda2/envs/R-scde/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /path/anaconda2/envs/R-scde/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.iso885915       LC_NUMERIC=C                  
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.iso885915        LC_COLLATE=en_US.iso885915    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.iso885915    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.iso885915   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.iso885915       LC_NAME=C                     
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C                   LC_TELEPHONE=C                
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.iso885915 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C           

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1


> capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE 
   http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

cairo is true in capabilities(). But the library cannot be loaded (no package).

Comment: You didn’t post the relevant error message (as it says: see config.log for details), nor which machine/version you’re on.

Comment: The output of `sessionInfo()` in R might also be helpful. Additionally, R can be configured to use cairo during installation. Check the output of `capabilities()` to see if you already have support (likely not, as you're having issues with the package).

Comment: yeah, I am still trying to locate config.log ...

Comment: What specifically do you need out of the Cairo package? If you're just looking for smoother-looking plots, then R should already be producing those by default, since your `capabilities()["cairo"]` is TRUE. Try doing `plot(1:10)`, and then `X11( type = "Xlib" ); plot(1:10)`. You should see a noticeable difference, with the first plot looking much smoother because it's using Cairo.

Comment: Of course, if you need something else from the Cairo package, it would be good to get at the bottom of the install problem. But I'm afraid we would need to see the error message from your log file to get at the issue.